# Change URL view by client with HAPROXY

Tags: http, https, url-rewriting, haproxy

I am loadbalancing to a server and i dont want the url to change. The client has to see the same url that he typed.

For example if the client enters : test.domain.com
The haproxy balances between the backends and the client sees:
https://website.com/blabla/blablalogin.htmx

And i want the client to see only:
test.domain.com or even https://test.domain.com

Is it possible with HAProxy to rewrite an URL ?

I have been searching and i don't know how to do it !

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: *"For example if the client enters : test.domain.com The haproxy balances between the backends and the client sees..."* well,  no, that's not normal.  If the URL is changing, then something is probably misconfigured.  Do you have a working HAProxy setup, or is this question speculative?

Comment: I have a working HAProxy. this is a real situation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a working haproxy, the problem may be in the website itself. Make sure that the website uses relative URLs instead of fixed ones. Example: **Login link**: `/blablah/blablalogin.htmx` instead of `https://website.com/blabla/blablalogin.htmx`.

Comment: I can't change anything on the webservers.